# Invalid parameter value error of YAML file

Tags: python, aws-sdk-js

I am working on AWS organization : currently creating scp policies under AWS organization as below:

**Python file:**

```
policies = config['policies']

for policy in policies:
 try:
   OUPolicy = client.create_policy(
      Description=policy['description'],
      Name= policy['Name'],
      Content=policy['content'],
      Type='SERVICE_CONTROL_POLICY'
    )
```

**YAML file:**

```
 policies:
 - Name: xyz
   description: Service Control Policies for xyz
   content:
     Version: 2012-10-17
     Statement:
     - Effect: Allow
       Resource: "*"
       Action: "*"
     - Effect: Deny
       Resource: "*"
       Action: "*
```

I verified the YAML template and It is in proper format but still getting error as below:

```
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Content, value: {'Version': datetime.date(2012, 10, 17), 'Statement': [{'Effect': 'Allow', 'Resource': '*', 'Action': '*'}, {'Effect': 'Deny', 'Resource': '*', 'Action': '*'}]}, type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
```

Comment: It appears as if you aren't passing the content of the YAML file to `client.create_policy` according to its requirements. Guessing from the last part of the error message, it wants a string instead of a dictionary. I suggest you look up the documentation for that function.

Comment: I checked number of times but not able to identify the error ..Could you please help ? I really appreciate

Comment: What does the documentation of `client.create_policy` say about the `Content` parameter? We cannot know what the problem is unless you tell us exactly where this function comes from.

Comment: According to aws boto3 doc :

               response = client.create_policy(
                  Content='string',
                  Description='string',
                  Name='string',
                 Type='SERVICE_CONTROL_POLICY'
               )

Comment: Content (string) --
[REQUIRED]

The policy content to add to the new policy. For example, if you create a service control policy (SCP), this string must be JSON text that specifies the permissions that admins in attached accounts can delegate to their users, groups, and roles.  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation of `create_policy` that you've shown,

> Content (string) -- [REQUIRED] The policy content to add to the new
>   policy. For example, if you create a service control policy (SCP),
>   this string must be JSON text that specifies the permissions that
>   admins in attached accounts can delegate to their users, groups, and
>   roles.

you need to encode the dictionary `policy['content']` (which you've decoded from the YAML document) back to a JSON string.

You can do that using [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps):

```
import json

...

client.create_policy(
  ...
  Content=json.dumps(policy['content']),
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

```html
policies = config['policies']

for policy in policies:
 try:
   OUPolicy = client.create_policy(
      Description=policy['description'],
      Name= policy['Name'],
      Content=json.dumps(policy['content']),
      Type='SERVICE_CONTROL_POLICY'
    )
```